# Replace code in Javascript (<script></script>) by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, replace

for example, i have a javascript code like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        alert('hi');
    }
</script>
```

can we replace that code in PHP to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function example(){
        alert('hohoho');
    }
</script>
```

that i want to replace is text in the tag script.

is it possible?

Comment: You want to make the text dynamic inside alert?

Comment: no, i want to obfuscate that code.

Comment: @ChandraPutraWijaya any updates to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable to store the text to be alerted and then use it.

```
<?php
    $variable = "hohoho";// change this to what you want in alert.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function example(){
        alert('<?php echo $variable ?>');
    }
</script>
```

For `obfuscating` see [this](http://packer.50x.eu/), [this](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) and [this](http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/index.php)

Comment: the point is not the variable/string. but i want to obfuscate that javascript, all function or variable that include in javasccript tag(<script></script>)

Comment: you want to `obfuscate` only alert part??

Comment: all part that include in script tag
<script>
//this part gonna be obfuscate
</script>

Comment: yes, i have try to use packer. but that must be a file

Comment: check this, it might help you, http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/index.php

Comment: thanks before mate, but i dont want to use tool. it must be generate by PHP(using any library)

Comment: or use any `encryption` and `decryption` for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to put all JavaScript tags inside php but remember php get executed once at server side when page get called by client but JavaScript will executed on client side call (browser side).

So you can do some thing like this and it will work, just to answer your question but it is not a good practice, you should have reason to use it:

```
<?php
$content = '<script type="text/javascript">
    function example(){
        alert("hohoho");
    }
</script>';

if (true)
    echo $content;
?>


<script>example();</script>
```